# Can't make text bold in PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm new to PHP and trying to write a PHP script to output some text in boldface. I've tried every combination of echo / print, `< b>` / `< strong>`  but no matter what, the output is always like this: `<strong>Text</strong>`

```
<?php
    print "<strong>Text</strong>";
?>
```

Why is this happening? I'm using PhpStorm, could there be a setting I have to fix?

Comment: something wrong with your  configuration. what server are u working on ??

Comment: Screenshots please

Comment: I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: Are these the only HTML tags that you have trouble with? What about `<table>`, `<div>`, etc.?

Comment: Man .. you are running your code in a console (CLI mode). Of course it ill show `<strong>Text</strong>` as is... it's not browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are opening your php file in your localhost. For example your filename is index.php you should run it at *localhost/index.php*. PHP scripts do not run when u just open it in your browser like HTMLs.

Can you add the current URL you are working with?

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question, where he sees the PHP source code. His problem is that HTML markup isn't being rendered.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that! When I try to open it in my browser it says "Object not found!", do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Screenshot please.

Answer (score 0):

check that which content-type it is. Make sure the `text/html` is correct. And also you should put some screenshots of your web server configuration.

Comment: Where can I check the content-type?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont have the correct settings in the project for the HTML to be loaded properly, e.g. not the correct meta settings
Try this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      print "Text\n";
      print "<b>Text</b>";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

If it doesn't work, try this meta tag instead:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**UPDATE:**

The reason this could happen, is because you have a PHP file, but you are using HTML within your PHP file - which is okay, but you have to render/return the php within html tags. For this to be rendered, you have to render the HTML within an HTML tag, or the HTML tags wont be rendered. Right now you are rendering HTML without having referenced the HTML anywhere.

What you could do is in the php tag in the html file, within body, specify a function:

```
<b><?php outputtext(); ?></b>
```

In your PHP file you specify the function as

```
function outputtext() {
  return "hello world";
}
```

Comment: Make the file an HTML file :)